Difficulty Training Multi-Output CNN-LSTM for Time Series Forecasting
I'm trying to train a Multi-Output CNN-LSTM-Attention model for time series forecasting on a Solar dataset with  multiple target variables. the outliers detection algorithms (IQR, zscore) identified 2000 data points as outliers but in reality these points are considered as normal picks that can occurs.
The dataset contains 3 features and target variables (irradiation, temperature, humidity) for time series forecasting.
Model Architecture:
I'm using a Multi-Output CNN-LSTM-Attention architecture as mentionned in the code below:
import pickle
import joblib
ahead=24
def signal_segmentation(dt,steps,ahead):
    end=0
    start=0
    x=[]
    y=[]
    for i in range(steps,dt.shape[0]):
        if i+ahead<dt.shape[0]:
            x.append(dt[i-steps:i,:])
            y.append(dt[i:i+ahead,:])
    return np.array(x),np.array(y)

from tensorflow.keras.losses import MeanAbsoluteError
from keras.regularizers import L1L2
from keras.layers import LeakyReLU
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, BatchNormalization
from keras import regularizers
n_hours=24
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
print("steps:",n_hours)
x,y=signal_segmentation(data4.values,n_hours,ahead)

import pickle
import joblib
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler,StandardScaler,RobustScaler
from tensorflow.keras.losses import MeanAbsoluteError
from keras.regularizers import L1L2
from keras.layers import LeakyReLU
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, BatchNormalization
from keras import regularizers
features=x.shape[2]
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x=np.reshape(x,(x.shape[0],x.shape[1]*x.shape[2]))
scaler = RobustScaler().fit(x)
joblib.dump(scaler, 'scaler_model.pkl')
x=scaler.transform(x)
print(x.shape)
print(y.shape)
train_size=int(len(x)*0.85)
print(train_size)
#x_trainlstm, x_testlstm, y_trainlstm, y_testlstm = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.1,shuffle=True)
x_trainlstm, x_testlstm = x[:train_size,:], x[train_size:,:]
y_trainlstm, y_testlstm = y[:train_size], y[train_size:]
x_trainlstm=np.array(x_trainlstm, dtype=np.float64)
y_trainlstm=np.array(y_trainlstm, dtype=np.float64)
x_testlstm=np.array(x_testlstm, dtype=np.float64)
y_testlstm=np.array(y_testlstm, dtype=np.float64)
x_trainlstm=np.reshape(x_trainlstm,(x_trainlstm.shape[0],n_hours,features))
x_testlstm=np.reshape(x_testlstm,(x_testlstm.shape[0],n_hours,features))
print(x_trainlstm.shape)
print(y_trainlstm.shape)
print(x_testlstm.shape)
print(y_testlstm.shape)

!pip install attention
from tensorflow.keras import layers

from attention import Attention
x_trainlstm=np.reshape(x_trainlstm,(x_trainlstm.shape[0],n_hours,features))
x_testlstm=np.reshape(x_testlstm,(x_testlstm.shape[0],n_hours,features))
class Attention(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Attention, self).__init__()

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.W = self.add_weight(shape=(input_shape[-1], 1),
                                 initializer='random_normal',
                                 trainable=True)
        super(Attention, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, inputs):
        attention_weights = keras.backend.dot(inputs, self.W)
        attention_weights = keras.backend.squeeze(attention_weights, axis=-1)
        attention_weights = keras.backend.softmax(attention_weights, axis=-1)
        attention_weights = keras.backend.expand_dims(attention_weights, axis=-1)
        weighted_inputs = inputs * attention_weights
        return keras.backend.sum(weighted_inputs, axis=1)

import pickle
import joblib
ahead=24
def signal_segmentation(dt,steps,ahead):
    end=0
    start=0
    x=[]
    y=[]
    for i in range(steps,dt.shape[0]):
        if i+ahead<dt.shape[0]:
            x.append(dt[i-steps:i,:])
            y.append(dt[i:i+ahead,:])
    return np.array(x),np.array(y)

from tensorflow.keras.losses import MeanAbsoluteError
from keras.regularizers import L1L2
from keras.layers import LeakyReLU
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, BatchNormalization
from keras import regularizers
n_hours=24
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
print("steps:",n_hours)
x,y=signal_segmentation(data4.values,n_hours,ahead)

import pickle
import joblib
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler,StandardScaler,RobustScaler
from tensorflow.keras.losses import MeanAbsoluteError
from keras.regularizers import L1L2
from keras.layers import LeakyReLU
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, BatchNormalization
from keras import regularizers
features=x.shape[2]
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x=np.reshape(x,(x.shape[0],x.shape[1]*x.shape[2]))
scaler = RobustScaler().fit(x)
joblib.dump(scaler, 'scaler_model.pkl')
x=scaler.transform(x)
print(x.shape)
print(y.shape)
train_size=int(len(x)*0.85)
print(train_size)
#x_trainlstm, x_testlstm, y_trainlstm, y_testlstm = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.1,shuffle=True)
x_trainlstm, x_testlstm = x[:train_size,:], x[train_size:,:]
y_trainlstm, y_testlstm = y[:train_size], y[train_size:]
x_trainlstm=np.array(x_trainlstm, dtype=np.float64)
y_trainlstm=np.array(y_trainlstm, dtype=np.float64)
x_testlstm=np.array(x_testlstm, dtype=np.float64)
y_testlstm=np.array(y_testlstm, dtype=np.float64)
x_trainlstm=np.reshape(x_trainlstm,(x_trainlstm.shape[0],n_hours,features))
x_testlstm=np.reshape(x_testlstm,(x_testlstm.shape[0],n_hours,features))
print(x_trainlstm.shape)
print(y_trainlstm.shape)
print(x_testlstm.shape)
print(y_testlstm.shape)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
predictions = modelCNNLSTM.predict(x_trainlstm)
print(predictions[0].shape)
print(len(predictions))
y_test_true = [y_trainlstm[:, :, i] for i in range(y_trainlstm.shape[2])]

for i in range(len(predictions)):
    feature_index = i + 1
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
    plt.plot(y_test_true[i][:500,0].flatten(), label='True Values')
    plt.plot(predictions[i][:500,0].flatten(), label='Predicted Values')
    plt.title(f'Feature {feature_index} Prediction vs True Values')
    plt.xlabel('Time Step')
    plt.ylabel(f'Feature {feature_index}')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()

    # Calculate metrics
    mse = mean_squared_error(y_test_true[i].flatten(), predictions[i].flatten())
    mae = mean_absolute_error(y_test_true[i].flatten(), predictions[i].flatten())
    R2 = r2_score(y_test_true[i].flatten(), predictions[i].flatten())
    print(f'Feature {feature_index} - MSE: {mse}, MAE: {mae}, R2: {R2}')
    
print("*****************************")
predictions = modelCNNLSTM.predict(x_testlstm)

y_test_true = [y_testlstm[:, :, i] for i in range(y_testlstm.shape[2])]

for i in range(len(predictions)):
    feature_index = i + 1
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
    plt.plot(y_test_true[i][:500,0].flatten(), label='True Values')
    plt.plot(predictions[i][:500,0].flatten(), label='Predicted Values')
    plt.title(f'Feature {feature_index} Prediction vs True Values')
    plt.xlabel('Time Step')
    plt.ylabel(f'Feature {feature_index}')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()

    # Calculate metrics
    mse = mean_squared_error(y_test_true[i].flatten(), predictions[i].flatten())
    mae = mean_absolute_error(y_test_true[i].flatten(), predictions[i].flatten())
    R2 = r2_score(y_test_true[i].flatten(), predictions[i].flatten())
    print(f'Feature {feature_index} - MSE: {mse}, MAE: {mae}, R2: {R2}')


I tried the differents normalization approaches, differents deep learning models from basic to advanced, i did hyperparameters tuning, differents loss functions, but i got same results or less sometimes.
Question:
I'm looking for suggestions on how to improve the model's performance on specific features (Feature 1 and potentially Feature 3).
Are there any techniques or modifications to the model architecture that could help address this issue?
What can be the source of these problems?[[[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/TPuuEUJj.png)](https://i.sstatic.net/5xD1JgHO.png)](https://i.sstatic.net/ACk5VN8J.png)
